# Error when try to get undistorted images after camera calibration and adding camera matrix and distortion coefficients

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I've used the sample OpenCV program to calculate the camera matrix and distortion coefficients from my camera and produced an xml file with the relevant data.
No I would like to correct distortion in some images taken from the same camera. So I create the program but still got some error. I'm trying to use it to get undistort image.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include "cameracalibrator.h"

CameraCalibrator::CameraCalibrator() :
    flag(0),
    mustInitUndistort(true)
{
}

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(){
Mat src,gray,image;

Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat1d(3, 3) <<  8.5033354550764898e+002, 0, 640, 0, 8.5033354550764898e+002, 360, 0, 0, 1);
Mat distortionCoefficients = (Mat1d(1, 5) << -4.2796890539434634e-001, 2.8770882755049054e-001, 0, 0, -1.4405356460809188e-001);

// remove distortion in an image (after calibration)
cv::Mat CameraCalibrator::remap(const cv::Mat &image) {

    cv::Mat undistorted;
    cv::Mat image=imread("C:/Users/NTU/Desktop/Test/im4.png");

    if (mustInitUndistort) { // called once per calibration

        cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(
            cameraMatrix,  // computed camera matrix
            distCoeffs,    // computed distortion matrix
            cv::Mat(),     // optional rectification (none) 
            cv::Mat(),     // camera matrix to generate undistorted
//          cv::Size(640,480),
            image.size(),  // size of undistorted
            CV_32FC1,      // type of output map
            map1, map2);   // the x and y mapping functions

        mustInitUndistort= false;
    }

    // Apply mapping functions
    cv::remap(image, undistorted, map1, map2, 
        cv::INTER_LINEAR); // interpolation type

    return undistorted;

imshow("gg",undistorted);
while(uchar(waitKey(1))!='Q');
//return 0;
}
}
```

when run got this error :

```
error: qualified-id in declaration before '(' token
 cv::Mat CameraCalibrator::remap(const cv::Mat &image) {
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you defining a member function nested *inside* the `main` function? That's not allowed. Perhaps you should take a few steps back, [get a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read, and start over?

Comment: ok.. So how to reconstruct the code?